# How to fix this C++ global-pointer-to-object hack?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, global

Currently, I have code like:

```
static YAML::Node *doc;
...
__attribute__((constructor)) void inityaml() {
    doc = new YAML::Node;
    parser.GetNextDocument(*doc);
}
```

The question is, is there any more C++-conventions-ish way to perform this task, like the use of a global reference or something?

Comment: Can you more fully describe what you are trying to achieve with this? To put it another way, why do you currently have code like this?

Comment: Unless you describe the complete context, you can simply do `YAML::Node* inityaml()` and return `doc` from function.

Comment: Or keep `inityaml()` as `void`-returning, and move the static declaration into the function.

Comment: At least make it a smart pointer. As it is, you're allocating the wrong amount of memory.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` when using C++? Use new instead

Comment: To answer the context question first, `inityaml` is an `__attribute__((constructor))`'d function which is called when my library is initialized. I need to use `doc` in other places in my library so I'd like to keep it global.

Comment: Secondly, to answer the `malloc` question, I figured philosophically what I wanted to was to open up space for a C++ object, and not initialize the object itself (which is done by `GetNextDocument()`)

Comment: @Matoe - Your `malloc` does not match the declaration for `doc`

Comment: Thanks to the observatins in the comments, I've edited my code and re-worded my question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not avoid heap allocation altogether?

i.e.

```
static YAML::Node doc;
...
void inityaml() {
    parser.GetNextDocument(&doc);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be passing a pointer, not a reference (which the function seems to want)?

Comment: @Xymostech - There was an error in the original code. I tried to make an educated guess.

Comment: No, I don't think there wasn't an error in the original code. It does take a reference. You can see an example of usage [here](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/HowToParseADocument#Basic_Parsing).

Comment: @Xymostech - `doc = malloc(sizeof(YAML::Node *));` the `malloc` returns a `YAML::Node **`. So I thought that the `GetNextDocument` requires `YAML::Node *`

Comment: `malloc` returns a `void*`, which they're storing in a `YAML::NODE *`. If you look at the example code, you'll see that `GetNextDocument` does not take a pointer. Their original code is very wrong, but it's not the types.

Comment: @Xymostech = The malloc is allocating enough space to store a pointer to `YAML:Node` and returning a pointer to that space i.e. `YAML::Node **`